# Kentico 10 BasicRepeater - implementing custom navigation between items

Tags: kentico

I have a list of custom items of the same page type being displayed in a basic repeater with a page size of 1.  I want to implement my own navigation for the back and forward through the items.

I tried using a Text / XML transformation so I'm not sure if I have to revert to using ASCX.

However DataItemCount works fine for the number of items but not the current "item" index.  I have tried DataItemIndex and DisplayIndex which are always zero.  I have tried accessing the current Pager (although ideally I want to hide this) but am not 100% sure how to reference it.

I also need to be able to navigate to the next and previous item. I'm sure I could make use of the querystring page parameter in a custom method but don't know how to write or how to call this.  I am struggling to find examples which don't simply involve evaluating a column value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a carousel. I'd go with javascript solution for this: it is more efficient as it does not reload the page when you navigate between items.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Decided to stick with the ease of using a repeater and transformation.  As the content gets cached and there's not too many items I don't think the initial overhead will be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/previous-and-next-links-to-listed-pages

It for version 8.2, but with none or a little code adjustment it should work in any version.

Comment: Thanks but it sounds like its very structured (ie. you specify text/image for the next previous links) - so I don't think it would have the flexibility to complete customise look and feel.  Thankfully I got the repeater working using custom extension methods and the querystring value via the transformation

Comment: The next/previous link code can hold full HTML markup with text and images and you can also apply css styles to the parent element, but if you have it implemented already, then good for you :)